# ReCaptcha - Chrome Hidding Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

Hearing that **ReCaptcha** can read all the ***extensions*** (or tampermonkey scripts) someone has on his pc, is there any way to evade this?
Any type of script or piece of code or settings.

This ***theory*** was confirmed: Once I login into any site with `Chrome Automation Extension`, I get flagged immediately. Even tho it just exposes an API of Chrome Options for another task that has nothing to do with recaptcha. Just loading any webpage(site) with ReCaptcha will trigger the captcha.

Here's the background.js, How change it to be unnoticeable to other apps?

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

/*
 * Checks for an extension error that occurred during the asynchronous call.
 * If an error occurs, will invoke the error callback and throw an exception.
 *
 * @param {function(!Error)} errCallback The callback to invoke for error
 *     reporting.
 */
function checkForExtensionError(errCallback) {
  if (typeof(chrome.extension.lastError) != 'undefined') {
    var error = new Error(chrome.extension.lastError.message);
    errCallback(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Captures a screenshot of the visible tab.
 *
 * @param {function(string)} callback The callback to invoke with the base64
 *     encoded PNG.
 * @param {function(!Error)} errCallback The callback to invoke for error
 *     reporting.
 */
function captureScreenshot(callback, errCallback) {
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab({format:'png'}, function(dataUrl) {
    if (chrome.extension.lastError &&
        chrome.extension.lastError.message.indexOf('permission') != -1) {
      var error = new Error(chrome.extension.lastError.message);
      error.code = 103;  // kForbidden
      errCallback(error);
      return;
    }
    checkForExtensionError(errCallback);
    var base64 = ';base64,';
    callback(dataUrl.substr(dataUrl.indexOf(base64) + base64.length))
  });
}

/**
 * Launches an app with the specified id.
 *
 * @param {string} id The ID of the app to launch.
 * @param {function()} callback Invoked when the launch event is complete.
 * @param {function(!Error)} errCallback The callback to invoke for error
 *     reporting.
 */
function launchApp(id, callback, errCallback) {
  chrome.management.launchApp(id, function() {
    checkForExtensionError(errCallback);
    callback();
  });
}
```

MANIFEST:

```
{
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDr+Q7QFcTr4Wmn9sSICKWbxnYLhIM0ERbcapZCDmpAkiBUhOPt+KkYnTdUFl4Kx2xv02MwIowh36Fho9Dhqh7cPWGIPsLHUaJosO6t6oaHxQsMQS/K4MlnP5pNJykExo82DcajSXGV+mIQH3RslxL+XhtmIh2BQLwbizVG0bA+mwIDAQAB",
  "name": "Chrome Automation Extension",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Exposes extension APIs for automating Chrome",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
     "tabs", "management", "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Instead of guessing and inventing consipracy theories, simply inspect the source of that extension - it makes its presence known in the main page DOM by adding various elements, which is trivial to detect for any page script including ReCaptcha.

Comment: Isn't much of a conspiracy if that's exactly what I thought. Obviously, I don't understand the logic behind it other ways I wouldn't be asking these questions. Would be more useful if you could provide me with a actual code or addon, js or another solution.

Comment: Which code? You can inspect the extension's code yourself e.g. by installing it and looking at the files in your browser profile. There's also CRXViewer extension that shows the source code of other extensions in the web store without the need to install them.

Comment: There you go thanks

Comment: I don't see how the posted code is related to the question - I need to see the entire extension (preferably) to make an educated guess or at least manifest.json and the content scripts. Extensions that don't add things to web page DOM and don't expose their stuff via web_accessible_resources aren't visible to web apps.

Comment: I've added the manifest to the stackoverflow website, that's' what  I meant.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me here. What do you mean by "I've added it to the site" ? Chrome extensions API like chrome.tabs or chrome.extension can't be used by sites.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188645/discussion-between-elvir-muslic-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 1):

You can read a lot of information about reCaptcha and how to cheat it from this pdf. [I’m not a human: Breaking the Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-16/materials/asia-16-Sivakorn-Im-Not-a-Human-Breaking-the-Google-reCAPTCHA-wp.pdf)

Google reCaptcha checks malicious actions using these details:

- Browsing History
- Browser Environment
- Canvas Rendering
- Screen Resolution and Mouse
- User-Agent

If anything is wrong (eg: browser version is not matched with user agent or suspicious mouse move was detected) reCaptcha requires verification.

PS: Actually I think recaptcha doesn't look for extensions (also it's not possible, because browsers don't give permission to list extensions), except it can detect if any extension has injected suspicious code to the website.

You can also check the de-obfuscated source code of reCaptcha [here](https://github.com/neuroradiology/InsideReCaptcha).

Comment: I've gotten an answer that it does seem that recaptcha checks if any html (generated from the extension) is insereted. Basically a footprint of the extension.
if the extension generates a tag for instance `<tagbygoogleextension>Hey</tagbygoogleextension>` could be anywhere generated. So it does seem it checks for that (it is confirmed) I'm just looking for a way to bypass it.